# How to estimate this special integral?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, special-functions

Let $\theta\in(0,\pi)$, and
$$
{\rm I}\left(\lambda,\theta\right)
=
\int_{\theta}^{2\pi - \theta}
\left[({1 \over \sin\left(t\right)}\frac{\partial}{\partial t})^{k}{\rm e}^{\left({\rm i}\lambda - 1\right)t}\right]
{\sin\left(t\right) \over \sqrt{\cos\left(\theta\right) - \cos\left(t\right)\,}\,}
\,{\rm d}t
$$
I want to know the asymptotic behavior when $\theta$ near $0$, and I also want to know if there is a more clear expression of this integral. I guess it may relate to the Bessel function. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did this integral come from?

Comment: this is relating to the wave kernel on the sphere when the dimension is $n=2k$